# Thinkorswim and Ubuntu 22.04.1 jammy

Tags: gui

Why is my thinkorswim graphic (GUI) not appearing?

I upgraded to 22.04.1 and doing so removed TD Ameritrade's Thinkorswim. I installed thinkorswim again successfully.  However, it only fully open once in both the live and paper trade.

When I click on the ThinkorSwim desktop icon, the login popup appears, I log in, thinkorswim updates happen, the background browser screen goes black for a second then the open program icon appears in my side tray, but no graphic.

It seems thinkorswim is running but the display isn't there.  This is because when I right click on the open program icon and choose to quit a new small window opens asking me to confirm the quit.

I can also see the phrase java-lang-Thread up on the top bar.  It goes away upon the close.[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzEkN.jpg)

I had no problems before the upgrade.

Thank you.

---

The next day... I left the thinkorswim applicaiton open overnight and when I opened up my laptop this afternoon the GUI was there and working.

I have an older laptop and a slow internet connection, so maybe it just takes a while to open with the new Ubuntu release.

ubfan1 suggested looking at the show applications to see if thinkorswim is open with a different name.  I didn't find it.

Below is another screenshot of the processes running when thinkorswim is open.

I think the Ubuntu and/or thinkorswim developers will work this out eventually.

Thank you.[Screen Shot of Processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlgAr.jpg)

---

Here is the link for the Zulu OpenJDK download from TDAmeritrade
[TD Zulu Link](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/faq/technical#q_011111111111111114)

I have to admit, I'm afraid to close thinkorswim

---

Later that day I closed thinkorswim, opened it again, and left to do something else.  I came back about 2 hours later and the GUI was operational.

Comment: Maybe it opened on a different display, click on the App library on the bottom of the launch bar, and see the top listing of open programs.

Comment: Thank you ubfan1.  Please see the edited post.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 defaults to two desktops, and while a four finger swipe may work to change desktops, I find the app list shows the two desktops right under the search bar, with windows of what's running on each -- click on a desktop to select it.I did the install without the zulu java, and up to the login, seems to work, but without an account, can't go any further.

Comment: Thank you ubfan1.  I wasn't aware of the two desktops.  When I open the Applicaitons feature without anything else open, choose the right most desktop and open thinkorswim,  it opens within a reasonable amount of time.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04 defaults to two desktops, and while a four finger swipe may work to change desktops, selecting desktops from the app list works for me. Click on the App library on the bottom of the launch bar.  The two desktops are right under the search bar, with windows of what's running on each -- click on a desktop to select it.I did the install without the zulu java, and up to the login, seems to work, but without an account, can't go any further.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It is like the desktop application window has disappeared. What I did was select the window using Super+TAB and then used the keyboard shortcut to maximize the window ALT+F10. That displayed the application. Then clicking on the un-maximize button made it normal again.